# How to run Hadoop HDFS command from java code

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, hdfs

I'm new in Hadoop! How can I run some hdfs commands from Java code? I've been testing successfully mapreduce with java code and hdfs commands directly from cloudera vm's terminal but now I'd like to learn how to do it with java code.
I've been looking for any materials where to learn but I haven't found yet.
Thanks

Comment: [Starting a process in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3774432/608639), [How do I launch a completely independent process from a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931536/608639), [How to get java getRuntime().exec() to run a command-line program with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13467307/608639), [Executing a Java application in a separate process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/636367/608639), etc.

Comment: @Robert Wagner Flores Almeida - https://princetonits.com/blog/technology/using-filesystem-api-to-read-and-write-data-to-hdfs/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16000840/write-a-file-in-hdfs-with-java should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Jagrut, you can use FileSystem API in your java code to interact with hdfs command. Below is the sample code where i am trying to check if a particular directory exists in hdfs or not. If exists, then remove that hdfs directory.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = new Job(conf,"HDFS Connect");

    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    Path outputPath = new Path("/user/cloudera/hdfsPath");
    if(fs.exists(outputPath))
        fs.delete(outputPath);
```

You can also refer to given blogs for further reference -

https://dzone.com/articles/working-with-the-hadoop-file-system-api, https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html
https://blog.knoldus.com/2017/04/16/working-with-hadoop-filesystem-api/

Answer (score 3):

I think this  may  be help to  you

I use it execute  shell command well  .here is the java example

```
public class JavaRunShell {
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        try {  
            String shpath="  your command";
            Process ps = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shpath);  
            ps.waitFor();  

            }  
        catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Ben Watson  are you sure  he wanted  hadoop code  not hadoop command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FileSystem API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) in your Java code to interact with HDFS.

Comment: Could you paste some code into your answer? That way if the page you're linking to disappears, your answer is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FileSystem API in java code to perform Hdfs commands.
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html

Please find the following sample code.

```
package com.hadoop.FilesystemClasses;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import com.hadoop.Constants.Constants;
public class HdfsFileSystemTasks {

public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HdfsFileSystemTasks.class
        .getName());

public FileSystem configureFilesystem(String coreSitePath,
        String hdfsSitePath) {
    FileSystem fileSystem = null;

    try {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Path hdfsCoreSitePath = new Path(coreSitePath);
        Path hdfsHDFSSitePath = new Path(hdfsSitePath);
        conf.addResource(hdfsCoreSitePath);
        conf.addResource(hdfsHDFSSitePath);

        fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
        return fileSystem;
    } catch (Exception ex) { 
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return fileSystem;
    }
}

    public String writeToHDFS(FileSystem fileSystem, String sourcePath,
        String destinationPath) {
    try {
        Path inputPath = new Path(sourcePath);
        Path outputPath = new Path(destinationPath);
        fileSystem.copyFromLocalFile(inputPath, outputPath);
        return Constants.SUCCESS;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Constants.FAILURE;
    }
}

 public String readFileFromHdfs(FileSystem fileSystem, String hdfsStorePath,
        String localSystemPath) {
    try {
        Path hdfsPath = new Path(hdfsStorePath);
        Path localPath = new Path(localSystemPath);
        fileSystem.copyToLocalFile(hdfsPath, localPath);
        return Constants.SUCCESS;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Constants.FAILURE;
    }
}

public String deleteHdfsDirectory(FileSystem fileSystem,
        String hdfsStorePath) {
    try {
        Path hdfsPath = new Path(hdfsStorePath);

        if (fileSystem.exists(hdfsPath)) {
            fileSystem.delete(hdfsPath);
            logger.info("Directory{} Deleted Successfully "
                    + hdfsPath);
        } else {
            logger.info("Input Directory{} does not Exists " + hdfsPath);
        }

        return Constants.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out
                .println("Some exception occurred while reading file from hdfs");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Constants.FAILURE;
    }
}

public String deleteLocalDirectory(FileSystem fileSystem,
        String localStorePath) {
    try {
        Path localPath = new Path(localStorePath);

        if (fileSystem.exists(localPath)) {
            fileSystem.delete(localPath);
            logger.info("Input Directory{} Deleted Successfully "
                    + localPath);
        } else {
            logger.info("Input Directory{} does not Exists " + localPath);
        }
        return Constants.SUCCESS;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out
                .println("Some exception occurred while reading file from hdfs");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return Constants.FAILURE;
    }
}


public void closeFileSystem(FileSystem fileSystem) {
    try {
        fileSystem.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unable to close Hadoop filesystem : " + ex);
    }
  }
}

package com.hadoop.FileSystemTasks;

import com.hadoop.Constants.HDFSParameters;
import com.hadoop.Constants.HdfsFilesConstants;
import com.hadoop.Constants.LocalFilesConstants;
import com.hadoop.FilesystemClasses.HdfsFileSystemTasks;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class ExecuteFileSystemTasks {

public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExecuteFileSystemTasks.class
        .getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {

    HdfsFileSystemTasks hdfsFileSystemTasks = new HdfsFileSystemTasks();
    FileSystem fileSystem = hdfsFileSystemTasks.configureFilesystem(
            HDFSParameters.CORE_SITE_XML_PATH,
            HDFSParameters.HDFS_SITE_XML_PATH);

    logger.info("File System Object {} " + fileSystem);

    String fileWriteStatus = hdfsFileSystemTasks.writeToHDFS(fileSystem,
            LocalFilesConstants.SALES_DATA_LOCAL_PATH,
            HdfsFilesConstants.HDFS_SOURCE_DATA_PATH);

    logger.info("File Write Status{} " + fileWriteStatus);

    String filereadStatus = hdfsFileSystemTasks.readFileFromHdfs(
            fileSystem, HdfsFilesConstants.HDFS_DESTINATION_DATA_PATH
                    + "/MR_Job_Res2/part-r-00000",
            LocalFilesConstants.MR_RESULTS_LOCALL_PATH);
    logger.info("File Read Status{} " + filereadStatus);

    String deleteDirStatus = hdfsFileSystemTasks.deleteHdfsDirectory(
            fileSystem, HdfsFilesConstants.HDFS_DESTINATION_DATA_PATH
                    + "/MR_Job_Res2");

    hdfsFileSystemTasks.closeFileSystem(fileSystem);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@HbnKing I tried running your code but I kept getting errors.  This is the error i got

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "your": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot 
 find the file specified
       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknowenter code heren Source)
       at jrs.main(jrs.java:5)
```