# issue with git blame command using java program

Tags: java, git, runtime

I am trying to run below git command using java program on windows.

```
 git --git-dir D:\code_coverage\.git blame  'src/RunCodeCoverage.java'
 | grep e4ecfbe | awk '{print $7}'
```

it gives me error :

```
fatal: cannot stat path '$7}'': No such file or directory
```

While running this command from command prompt, it gives me results as desired.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

On a CMD in Windows, I can make it work using double quotes for the `awk` parameters:

```
 git --git-dir D:\code_coverage\.git blame  'src/RunCodeCoverage.java'
 | grep e4ecfbe | awk "{print $7}"
```

Note that my `awk.exe` comes from [Gnu On Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki).

The OP mentions using that command in Java with:

```java
String commandToBeExecuted="git --git-dir D:\code_coverage\.git blame 'src/RunCodeCoverage.java' | grep e4ecfbe | awk "{print $7}"'"; 
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToBeExecuted);
```

But you never pass all parameters as a single string.
Use an array, as in "[Using Quotes within getRuntime().exec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/161888/6309)" and in "[How to make pipes work with Runtime.exec()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5928316/6309)"

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", commandToBeExecuted);
```

Escape the double quotes in `commandToBeExecuted`:

```
 commandToBeExecuted = "git --git-dir D:\code_coverage\.git blame  'src/RunCodeCoverage.java'
 | grep e4ecfbe | awk \"{print $7}\""
```

Comment: Thanks VonC, it works through CMD but while running it from java program using java Runtime then it give the mentioned error.:      fatal: cannot stat path '$7}'': No such file or directory

Comment: @ManishMankar what exact Java code are you using to pass the parameters to the java `Runtime.exec()` command?

Comment: String commandToBeExecuted="git --git-dir D:\code_coverage\.git blame  'src/RunCodeCoverage.java' | grep e4ecfbe | awk "{print $7}"'";                 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToBeExecuted);

Comment: @ManishMankar I have amended the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks@VonC! but still am getting issue "fatal: cannot stat path ''src/RunCodeCoverage.java'': No such file or directory
"

Comment: @ManishMankar add the right parent directory as a third parameter of `exec()`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File%29): http://stackoverflow.com/a/6811578/6309