# Cleartool commands not working using Java processbuilder

Tags: java, cleartool

I am trying to execute `cleartool` commands from batch script using Java `ProcessBuilder` but it is getting stuck at `rebase` command

```
[startview command is executed successfully (ERRORLEVEL = 0)]
```

When I try using `Runtime.exec` with command array `[{"cleartool.exe","<startview command>"}]`, it says

> cleartool Error: unrecognized command startview

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the [`cleartool rebase`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm) does not involve any interactive step (where it would stop and listen for input on stdin).

Make sure your CMD has, by default, in its `%PATH%` environment variable a path to `cleartool.exe`.
Then follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31199220/6309):

```
String commandToBeExecuted="cleartool xxx"
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd", "/c", commandToBeExecuted);
```

Since `cmd.exe` is blocked ("`cmd` is disabled"), the [OP A K Malik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648947/a-k-malik) confirms that not using an array works:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("<rebase command>")
```

Comment: problem is , we cant use cmd as it is disabled by he administrator. I will check for %PATH%

Comment: @AKMalik no, cmd should be available, there is no reason to disable it.

Comment: Its my office system and cmd is disabled.Anyway its working now. The problem was with the command. Thanks

Comment: @AKMalik what was the problem?

Comment: I was using command array, and when I converted the whole command into single array it worked. [runtime.exec("<rebase command>") instead of runtime.exec({"cleartool.exe","rebase command"}) ]

Comment: @AKMalik OK. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.