# Unable to open file in explorer when there comma in file name

Tags: java, swing

Hi I tried  to open a file in explorer for a chat application using java, using the code 
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select," + recievedFile);`

It works fine except when there is `comma(",")` in file name.

I cannot replace `comma(",")` with empty space or some other characters because I have to preserve the file name.

Any other possibilities? Without altering the file name? I must have the file selected and opened in a new explorer window. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161859/using-quotes-within-getruntime-exec

Comment: Does surrounding the name with double quotes work? And do you really have a file that is called `comma(",")`? Can you add the **real** filename?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters (or comma characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like this to able to open files with comma in file name:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select,\"" + recievedFile + "\"");
```