# Executing python script from Netbeans and reading output, FAILS in one case but not another

Tags: java, python, netbeans

I am currently heeding advice from this Stack Overflow post:

[Call and receive output from Python script in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097491/call-and-receive-output-from-python-script-in-java)  (which links to http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016 for getting the output)

So, that's great and all, and I used it for the following code successfully:

```
        String directPath;
        if (Files.exists(Paths.get("C:/Users/jiaqin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NCHandler/nchandlerv2/NCPythonFiles/"))) {
            directPath = "C:/Users/jiaqin/Documents/NetBeansProjects/NCHandler/nchandlerv2/NCPythonFiles/";
        }
        else {
            directPath = "/home/lab/testNetconf/NCPythonFiles/net_back_end/";
        }

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python " + directPath + "get_platform_and_OS.py -ssh_ip " + ui.ssh_ip
        + " -username " + ui.username + " -password " + ui.password);
        Scanner threeInfo = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());


        String hostName = "";
        String IP_Address = ui.ssh_ip;
        String OS = "";
        String platform = "";

        int iter = 0;
        while (threeInfo.hasNextLine()) {
            switch(iter) {
                case 0:
                    hostName = threeInfo.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    OS = threeInfo.nextLine();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    platform = threeInfo.nextLine();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            iter ++;
        }

        threeInfo.close();

        Label hostNameLabel = new Label(hostName);
        Label sshLabel = new Label("SSH IP Address: " + IP_Address);
        Label OSLabel = new Label(OS);
        Label platformLabel = new Label(platform);
```

Essentially, I run a python script by determining its path first, then I read the output using a Scanner (instead of a BufferedReader like in the post). Based on that case, I have a later method that uses the exact same concept:

```
public static String verifyShowCommands(String[] showCommands, MainUI ui) {
    try {
        String errorText = "";

        String retErrors = "";

        System.out.println("Python exec command is:\n" + "python /home/lab/testNetconf/NCPythonFiles/net_back_end/verify_show_commands.py -ssh_ip " + ui.ssh_ip + " -username " 
                + ui.username + " -password " + ui.password + " -show_commands \"" + String.join(", ", showCommands) + "\"");

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python /home/lab/testNetconf/NCPythonFiles/net_back_end/verify_show_commands.py -ssh_ip " + ui.ssh_ip + " -username " 
                + ui.username + " -password " + ui.password + " -show_commands \"" + String.join(", ", showCommands) + "\"");
        BufferedReader obtainedInfo = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String read = null;
        while ((read = obtainedInfo.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("New line found");
            retErrors += read;
        }
        System.out.println("Obtained Info is:" + retErrors + " and that's it");
        obtainedInfo.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < showCommands.length; i ++) {
            if (i < showCommands.length - 1) {
                int thisSCStart = retErrors.indexOf(showCommands[i]);
                int nextSCStart = retErrors.indexOf(showCommands[i+1]);
                String outputSC = retErrors.substring(thisSCStart, nextSCStart);
                if (outputSC.contains("'Valid': 'No'")) {
                    errorText += outputSC + "\n";
                }
            }
            else {
                String outputSC = retErrors.substring(retErrors.indexOf(showCommands[i]));
                if (outputSC.contains("'Valid': 'No'")) {
                    errorText += outputSC + "\n";
                }
            }
        }
        return errorText;
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm once again running a python script and reading the output. The error occurs when I attempt to get the substring of retErrors - because retErrors is an empty string; that's right, for some reason, this time the output is NOT getting read. Note that the above uses BufferedReader; I was originally using Scanner, and when that failed I changed over because I thought maybe for god-knows-what reason, synchronization might affect the situation. Unfortunately, it seemed there was STILL no output to read.

As for how I know, I simply observed in the Netbeans output and searched for the line

```
System.out.println("Obtained Info is:" + retErrors + " and that's it");
```

Then, you might ask the obvious question: what if the command is invalid? Well, I printed out the entire exec command at the top as well:

```
        System.out.println("Python exec command is:\n" + "python /home/lab/testNetconf/NCPythonFiles/net_back_end/verify_show_commands.py -ssh_ip " + ui.ssh_ip + " -username " 
                + ui.username + " -password " + ui.password + " -show_commands \"" + String.join(", ", showCommands) + "\"");
```

So, I looked for that line in the Netbeans output, and there it was:

```
Info:   Python exec command is:
python /home/lab/testNetconf/NCPythonFiles/net_back_end/verify_show_commands.py -ssh_ip 9.0.0.12 -username root -password lab -show_commands "show bgp scale"
```

And then I copy-pasted that exact command into a terminal and ran it, and I got an output (the actual type of the printed result in the output is a dictionary, hence the brackets):

[image]

Anyone have some advice? This is extraordinarily frustrating to me because I'm following the exact format of the first case with get_platform_and_os.py but then with verify_show_commands.py, it just doesn't read anything.

As a side note, if this information helps, when I run the command manually in the terminal, it takes roughly 2-3 seconds to complete. However, running it in my project takes much less than a second before it errors out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

[Using Quotes within getRuntime().exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161859/using-quotes-within-getruntime-exec)

Apparently this is a thing. I just made every word in the command an array element instead, and inside the array, "show bgp scale" was entered without the quotes. After that, it worked.