# Issue executing a java compiled file from java source

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, java-runtime-compiler

I am trying to execute a java compiled file from another java program, and I am having some issues.

When I run from my terminal the command `java -cp ".:lib/MyLib.jar" javaFiles/g1/MyCompiledProgram` I can execute MyCompiledProgram without any issue.

But when I try to execute the same command from code using the following method:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("java -cp  \".:%s\" javaFiles/g1/MyCompiledProgram",Path.of(PATH_MYLIB)));
String error = null;
process.waitFor();
if(process.exitValue() != 0){
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getErrorStream())){
        error = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    }
    System.out.println(error);
}
```

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` error. I checked that the directory java was using to execute the command was correct (running the pwd command) and it is the correct one.

Does anyone has any idea why is not finding the class? Thanks :)

Comment: Really? The command works when run directly? That's weird, given that `javaFiles/g1/MyCompiledProgram` is not a class name. `javaFiles.g1.MyCompiledProgram` would be, if the `MyCompiledProgram.java` file started with `package javaFiles.g1;`, but that sounds unlikely.

Comment: Perhaps reading through the answer to [What does “Could not find or load main class” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18093928/5221149) might allow you to figure out what you're doing wrong.

Comment: I think the real problem is that `exec` doesn't understand shell quoting.  So those quote characters will be seen by the `java` command and it won't understand them.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the link, really useful information and yes, the command works when run directly, I am using Fedora System with a Fish terminal.

Comment: @StephenC I see, and how can I fix it? Is there any other method to execute .class files from other java source code?

Comment: Yea sure.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161859/using-quotes-within-getruntime-exec.

Comment: The Java class name *should* be given with `.`, not `/`, as separators. --- If you're on Windows, the path-separator *must* be `;`, not `:`. You can use `System.getProperty("path.separator")` to get the correct character for the platform you're on.